# Play activator unable to create new app in OSX

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am new to play framework and am trying to set up a simple app using Play activator. I have copied activator to my path and am using Jdk 8

When I run the command

> activator new first_app play-java

I get the below error

```
    Fetching the latest list of templates...




Sep 18, 2016 1:43:43 AM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient executeHelper
INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: peer not authenticated
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:431)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:390)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:562)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:280)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:165)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2951)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:885)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:941)
    at activator.templates.repository.UriRemoteTemplateRepository.downloadFromS3(UriRemoteTemplateRepository.scala:104)
    at activator.templates.repository.UriRemoteTemplateRepository.downloadTryingS3First(UriRemoteTemplateRepository.scala:135)
```

I have tried everything from installing openssl, using rvm etc. but I am not able to create the project.

Comment: Have you tried to deactivated your firewall ?

Comment: Yes. I turned off the firewall. I also tried turn off my antivirus but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Can you ping that address?